# Cannot implicitly convert User Principal to Web.Utility.UserPrincipalEx

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am trying to get an extension property from Active Directory.  So I have an extra class as below:

```
namespace MyProject.Web.Utility
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
[DirectoryObjectClass("Person")]
public class UserPrincipalEx : UserPrincipal
{
// Inplement the constructor using the base class constructor. 
public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context)
    : base(context)
{ }

// Implement the constructor with initialization parameters.    
public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context,
                     string samAccountName,
                     string password,
                     bool enabled)
    : base(context, samAccountName, password, enabled)
{ }

// Create the "extensionAttribute2" property.    
[DirectoryProperty("extensionAttribute2")]
public string ExtensionAttribute2
{
    get
    {
        if (ExtensionGet("extensionAttribute2").Length != 1)
            return string.Empty;

        return (string)ExtensionGet("extensionAttribute2")[0];
    }
    set { ExtensionSet("extensionAttribute2", value); }
}
}
```

I have attempted to use this in another class (in the same namespace) as below:

```
    using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        // Search the directory for the new object. 
        UserPrincipalEx inetPerson = UserPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity(ctx, identityName);

        string test = inetPerson.ExtensionAttribute2;

        // you can easily access the ExtensionAttribute2 now
        string department = inetPerson.ExtensionAttribute2;
    }
```

However - this throws the error below - I tried casting UserPrincipalEx to UserPrincipal but this did also not work - I also tried to call base.FindByIdentity which did not work - how can I resolve this?

```
Error   81  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal' to 'MyProj.Web.Utility.UserPrincipalEx'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: It is because `FindByIdentity` method returns `UserPrincipal` not `UserPrincipalEx`

Comment: ah ok - so I need to implement my own overload FindByIdentity in my UserPrincipalEx class :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - not enough coffee drank this morning - forgot to implement my own version of FindByIdentity in my UserPrincipalEx class.

```
    public static new UserPrincipalEx FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context,
                                                   string identityValue)
    {
        return (UserPrincipalEx)FindByIdentityWithType(context,
                                                     typeof(UserPrincipalEx),
                                                     identityValue);
    }
```